# can while loop python execute statement just once?

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have monitoring python script with notification
 this is my script

```
if COUNT != 0:
    print("Running!")
    text = process[0] + " process running"
    url = URL + "sendMessage?text={0}&chat_id={1}".format(text, CHAT_ID)
    # send message to groups
    requests.get(url)
```

how to make this keep looping when condition true and just sending message once

Comment: What statement do you want to run only once?

Comment: request.get(url) statement if no it will be spam message

Comment: Ok check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
flg = True
while COUNT != 0:
    print("Running!")
    if flg:
        text = process[0] + " process running"
        url = URL + "sendMessage?text={0}&chat_id={1}".format(text, CHAT_ID)
        # send message to groups
        requests.get(url)
        flg = False
```

you can use a flg variable to make the message sending code run only once.

Comment: how if the flg have dinamic value?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic value? In the example i provided the while loop will keep executing until count is not 0. But the message will be sent only once since flg will be true only once.

Comment: in my script count is for the time how long this monitoring script will run and flg is variable when the process is running so it will be not always true or false that example just a piece of script when process is running

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what you want the script to do. It was my understanding that you wanted to run the while loop till count wasn't zero but only send message once in the loop. Is this not what you want?

Comment: sorry if you didnt understand. thats what i want but flg varible is contain value of process i want to monitoring so that value will be true when process is running and false when process isn't running

Comment: flg is just a boolean. It changes value to false as soon as the if statement is executed once. So the flg variable will remain false for the rest of the while loop iterations and prevent the message being sent again. Not sure what you mean by dynamic

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

```
condition=True
while condition:
    if COUNT != 0:
        print("Running!")
        text = process[0] + " process running"
        url = URL + "sendMessage?text={0}&chat_id={1}".format(text, CHAT_ID)
        # send message to groups
        requests.get(url)
        condition=False
```

Comment: that will get out from loop that i want is loop keep run when request.get(url) just execute once it possible?